# Add Items to Windows Context Menu

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-interface, contextmenu

I am writing an app and I was wondering how could you add something to the windows context-menu (when you right click on the windows exspor) like in 7Zip or winRAR to preform certain actions i.e. encrypt file\zip file; in vb.net, or perhaps is there a way in the windows installer template?

I don't really want to use the shell method but if I have to I will.

Would really like the help in vb.net!

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to say that the application is creating a file type and you want to associate a context menu when a user right clicks on this file type in Windows Explorer.